Increase corrplot plotting area in visualization
How can I increase the plotting area of a corrplot for better visualization(i.e., make the graph bigger)
I´m using the following code to get the corrplot
cor_5 <- rcorr(as.matrix(datos))
M <- cor_5$r
p_mat <- cor_5$P

corrplot(M,type = "lower",p.mat = p_mat, order = "original", sig.level = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05), pch.cex = 0.9, 
         insig = 'label_sig',diag = FALSE, col = brewer.pal(n=8,name = "RdYlBu"), tl.col = "black", tl.cex = 0.8, tl.srt = 45,mar = c(0,7,7,0))


This is the image I get

The real name of my variables is a little bit larger (2- 3 words) and the resulting size of the plotting area is smaller. How can I get to use the whole visualization area?

Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

The datos object is not available to me nor it is possible to generate it via a reproducible example.
The corrplot package relies on base R, which means you can control the plotting area (and especially the margins) with functions like par(), mar(), or oma(). A nicely detailed explanation is available in the R graph gallery.
You need to run these commands before you plot with corrplot.
Best,
